# Why doesn't the for loop end?

Tags: c

I wrote a program defining the variable `np` as `int` and initializing it using `getchar`. But in this way the program wouldn't exit the `for`-loop. If I use `scanf` it runs fine. Why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct parents {
    char fathername[30];
    char Mothername[50];
} parents;

struct person {
    char firstname[30];
    char Lastname[30];
    int age;
    parents p;
};

int main() {
    int np;
    printf("The number of people: ");
    np = getchar(); //scanf("%d", &np);

    struct person *point = malloc(np * sizeof(struct person));

    int i = 0;
   
    for (i = 0; i < np; i++) {
        printf("Give your name: ");
        scanf("%s", &point[i].firstname);

        printf("Give your Lastname: ");
        scanf("%s", &point[i].Lastname);

        printf("Give your age: ");
        scanf("%d", &(point + i)->age);

        printf("Give the name of your father: ");
        scanf("%s", &point[i].p.fathername);

        printf("Give the name of your mother: ");
        scanf("%s", (point + i)->p.Mothername);

        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does `getchar()` return? Hint: `'9'` is  57 as far as the computer is concerned. I'm not sure why you abandoned the `scanf()` approach which at least has a hope of working here, though as always, **check the return code** of any function that can fail.

Comment: Why are you doing `np=getchar()`? There's no known encoding where e.g. `5 == '5'`. Why did you comment out `scanf("%d",&np)`?

Comment: PSA: You may want to get into the habit of keeping your `for` loop variables self-contained, as in `for (int i = 0; ...)` instead of declaring that outside the loop scope. This makes it easier to follow, and avoids unnecessary re-initialization like you have here. You'll also want to pick a single naming convention and not have, for no apparent reason, lowercase and capitalized structure components. C is extremely case sensitive, and that rubs off on any C programmer as well.

Comment: i used getchar because i dont know exactly how it works

Comment: Another thing to consider: This problem would become almost immediately obvious if you run this through a debugger as the value of `np` would make no sense until you realize what `getchar()` does by *checking the documentation*. This is a "loop" you should work on internalizing so you can quickly solve problems like this, as this is a lot of what programming really is.

Comment: It would be worth your while to learn how to use a debugger.  If you are using an IDE to help you write your programs then it probably has an integrated debugger. If not, then there are good command-line debuggers.  Running your program under control of a debugger would help you figure out what is going on.

Comment: There's really no reason to not know when [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) is a click away. If you run code without understanding it, that's how you can quickly get into trouble.

Comment: Well... don't use functions which you don't know how they work. Study them before using them.

Comment: If there's something you don't understand, then [*read about it*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar). Don't just blindly use it and hope it will work as you expect. Also, the name `getchar` is rather self-explanatory, it gets a *character*, not an integer value.

Answer (score 7):

Your program should end, just not where you expect it to, because `getchar` returns a `char`. In ASCII encoding, this means `'1'` becomes `49`, and while you would expect your loop to run once, it will run 49 times.

If you use the following, that same input means that `np` will contain the value `1`.

```
scanf("%d", &np);
```

### The issue with `scanf`

As suggested in [Govind Parmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77867467/15261315) but not elaborated on, the problem with using `scanf` to achieve this is that if `scanf` fails to read a valid integer from the user input, it will leave that invalid input in the buffer to be read again.

This will enter an infinite loop on *one* invalid input

```
int np;
int retval;

do {
    printf("np: ");
    retval = scanf("%d", &np);
} while (retval != 1 || np <= 0);
```

If we read in a line of input and then try to extract an int, each attempt will involve *new input* giving the user an opportunity to break out of it by entering valid input.

Answer (score 6):

You are limiting iterations of the `for` loop based on the value of `np`, which contains the *character representation* of the input, since it is read from `getchar()`.

This means that:

1. You can only read a single character of input for the iteration limitation.
2. There is no way of controlling that the user actually enters a valid digit, they can enter `a`, `b`, `?`, `:`, etc.
3. If the user does enter a valid digit, you are getting the numeric value of the *character* representing that digit (i.e. on ASCII, the input `1` would give `np` the value `0x31` (`49`)).

To read and validate numeric user input, you can use `fgets` to read the text input from the user, then `strtol` to attempt to parse the numeric value from the input:

```
char buffer[13]; // "-2147483648" longest possible int 32 value as base 10 text + \n\0
int np;

do
{
    printf("Enter the number of people: ");
    fgets(buffer, 13, stdin);
    np = strtol(buffer, NULL, 10);
}
while(np <= 0);
```

Comment: For completeness, negative values could cause problems: `Enter the number of people:  -812`  Also, error cases that return `LONG_MIN` or `LONG_MAX` should also be handled for robust code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Replaced do-while condition with `n <= 0` (was `0 == n`)

Comment: @AndrewHenle As for `LONG_MIN` and `LONG_MAX`. There are two possibilities: `long` is the same size as an `int`, or it is larger. If it is larger, then the values for `LONG_MIN` and `LONG_MAX` cannot be represented in an `int`. If it is the same size, then `LONG_MAX` and `LONG_MIN` are valid input values (though probably not very sensible for most conceivable use cases).

Comment: Indeed.  Robustly parsing integer inputs in a portable manner isn't easy.  You'd need to use an `long` temporary to ensure you can handle error conditions.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is `np = getchar()` is not equivalent to `scanf("%d", &np)`.  The first reads a single byte and stores its character code into `np` whereas the second attempts to read an integer from `stdin` and stores the converted value upon success.

`scanf` is full of quirks and pitfalls.  It take a long time to master and it is one of most misused function in the C library.

Here are some caveats:

- it is recommended to read a full line of input and use `sscanf()` or other functions to try and parse the line.
- do not use the `&` in front of array arguments, but do use `&` for scalar targets.
- let the compiler help check the argument types using extra warnings (eg: **gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror** or **clang -Weverything -Werror**).
- always give `scanf` the maximum number of characters that can be stored into the destination array before the null terminator for `%s` and `%[`: for example instead of `scanf("%s", &point[i].firstname)`, use

  ```
   scanf("%29s", point[i].firstname);
  ```
- always check the return value of `scanf` to detect and report invalid or missing input.
- do not mix `scanf` and `fgets`.